# Unable to verify TLS cert with only CommonName in NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm looking to create an NGINX reverse proxy to my WiFi router, and I'm looking to verify the connection. My router uses a self-signed certificate which lists the `tplinkwifi.net` domain as the Subject Common Name (CN) but doesn't include any Subject Alternative Names (SAN).

I've already tried this with Caddy as well, but [support documentation](https://caddy.community/t/with-caddy-x509-certificate-relies-on-legacy-common-name-field-use-sans-instead/18913) is clear that Caddy will not consider the CommonName. This is probably reasonable since it's been deprecated since around 2000, but since I'm stuck working with a legacy certificate I'm looking for a work-around.

I can't tell if NGINX will support this. The code has some legacy paths that mention [falling back to commonname](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blame/25c546ac37ba622b93c1a7075bd7eb447bac17b2/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c#L4865), but more recent releases rely on OpenSSL. I haven't done a code dive to confirm.

The problematic certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            [...]
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 2010 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 00:00:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                [...]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                [...]
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                [...]

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         [...]
```

I'm able to get `curl` to authenticate and connect if I use the server's certificate in `--cacert`:

```
$ curl --cacert cert.pem https://tplinkwifi.net/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
[...]
```

But not OpenSSL command line:

```
$ openssl s_client -servername tplinkwifi.net -connect tplinkwifi.net:443 -CAfile cert.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
   i:C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net

issuer=C = CN, CN = tplinkwifi.net

[...]
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
[...]
```

I suspect the issue is that I'm using `-CAfile` and the certificate has `CA:FALSE`.

In NGINX, I've tried the following:

```
events {
}

error_log /dev/stdout debug;

http {
  upstream tplinkwifi.net {
    server tplinkwifi.net:443;
  }

  server {
    access_log /dev/stdout,severity=debug;
    listen 80;
    server_name router;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://tplinkwifi.net;
      proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_verify on;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_name tplinkwifi.net;
      proxy_ssl_verify_depth 10;
    }
  }
}
```

When I connect I get a `502 Bad Gateway` and log output:

```
2023/04/27 07:16:51 [error] 29#29: *1 upstream SSL certificate verify error: (21:unable to verify the first certificate) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: router, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.0.1:443/", host: "router"
```

This looks consistent with the OpenSSL command line behavior I'm seeing (both fail to verify the certificate).

I'm aware I could just ignore the certificate with `curl -k` and NGINX's `proxy_ssl_verify off;`, but I'm looking to actually authenticate the connection and I'd prefer to pin the certificate my router uses. I'm aware I could change to a different router, but the router is already new. I'd prefer not to alter the router either.

I'm open to using a different reverse proxy software, if there's one that can support the legacy CommonName-only certificate my router uses. While the certificate is problematic, I think I'm able to get an authenticated connection if I can pin my reverse proxy to the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this mostly working.

I traced the NGINX error to `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`. Turns out, the certificate wasn't actually self signed. It was signed by a private CA, but that root wasn't included in the chain provided by the router. I didn't see a way to download the root either.

I made progress with OpenSSL next. Partial chain verification allows me to verify the leaf cert against itself, instead of needing to find the full chain and trust from the root:

```
openssl verify -partial_chain -CAfile tplink.pem tplink.pem
tplink.pem: OK
```

I traced `-partial_chain` through the OpenSSL code and found `OPT_V_PARTIAL_CHAIN` and `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN`. Interestingly, Curl [uses partial chain verification](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4655) by default. [Envoy supports this as a flag](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/22350), but I wanted to keep using NGINX.

I patched NGINX and compiled it:

```
diff --git a/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c b/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c
index 9cc202c9..8fc78ed0 100644
--- a/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c
+++ b/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c
@@ -4993,6 +4993,12 @@ ngx_http_proxy_set_ssl(ngx_conf_t *cf, ngx_http_proxy_loc_conf_t *plcf)
         return NGX_ERROR;
     }

+    {
+        // Patch: Permit partial chain verification
+        X509_STORE *store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(plcf->upstream.ssl->ctx);
+        X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN);
+    }
+
     cln = ngx_pool_cleanup_add(cf->pool, 0);
     if (cln == NULL) {
         ngx_ssl_cleanup_ctx(plcf->upstream.ssl);
```

This allowed NGINX to validate the leaf certificate against itself and it worked!

Unfortunately, my tplink router generates a new TLS certificate on every reboot, so trust broke at that point. That's where I gave up, but hopefully these notes help someone else.